# Windows Azure Media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am uploading video(.wmv) on azure programmatically .I am getting error 
**"Windows Azure Media Encoder detected media errors on source videoname.wmv:File type isn't supported"** and **"ErrorExecutingTaskUnsupportedFormat"**

Comment: Can you please post your code on how the upload is working and also are you sure it is a valid WMV. Just because the extension is, doesn't mean it actually is. Speculating, I would say that your file is being uploaded incorrectly hence delivering a file that Azure can't decode.

Comment: Case 1-In my case i am converting wmv file into bytes and then uploading bytes in blob ,asset is getting created but while encoding it gives above error but in case of .mp4 format asset is getting created and encoded properly. Case2-if i am uplaoding specifying the direct path of wmv for eg ("C:\\myfolder\video.wmv) in this case it is getting uploaded ,encoded properly

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using to upload. Both the working version and the non-working version.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41c30130-e44a-46f0-9aaf-b30a9e1250e6/file-type-not-supported-on-encoding-asset-on-azure?forum=MediaServices

Answer (score 1):

To the close on this question, Azure Media Services supports WMV as input format - very likely you are not uploading file correctly.The following quickstart uses Azure Media Services .NET SDK Extensions to upload a wmv file and encode it to H264 adaptive bitrate MP4 set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569319.aspx .

Comment: in the QuickStart the file seems to be uploaded from the server. If my web app is asking the user to upload a file do I still have to upload the file to the server and then push to azure blob or is there a way to directly upload the file from the client machine to azure? Also, is there any known changes to be made if using asp.net core?